# Error installing MEAD, no such file or directory: 'prank.o'

Tags: perl, compiler-errors

I am not quite sure why I am getting this error when installing [MEAD](http://www.summarization.com/mead/). Does anyone have a idea how I can fix this? I need to install MEAD for a school homework and I don't have much experience with Perl.

```
Fixing perl directives:
  bin/default-classifier.pl
  bin/default-reranker.pl
  bin/driver.pl
  bin/extract-to-summary.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/Centroid.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/IsLongestSentence.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/Length.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/Position.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/QueryCosine.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/QueryCosineNoIDF.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/QueryWordOverlap.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/SimWithFirst.pl
  bin/feature-scripts/Skeleton.pl
  bin/identity-reranker.pl
  bin/leadbased-classifier.pl
  bin/make-CHIN-docsent.pl
  bin/mead.pl
  bin/meadeval.pl
  bin/novelty-reranker.pl
  bin/random-classifier.pl
  bin/read-idf.pl
  bin/relative-utility.pl
  bin/sentjudge-to-extract.pl
  bin/write-idf.pl

Fixing $MEADDIR in MEAD::MEAD


Building English IDF DBM:
Wd: 65300


Building Chinese IDF DBM:
Wd: 54700


******** Compiling LexRank ********
In file included from prank.cpp:10:
./prmain.h:80:8: error: unknown type name 'pthread_mutex_t'; did you mean
      'pthread_attr_t'?
extern pthread_mutex_t *mu; /* For general use */
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       pthread_attr_t
/usr/include/sys/_types/_pthread_attr_t.h:30:34: note: 'pthread_attr_t' declared
      here
typedef __darwin_pthread_attr_t         pthread_attr_t;
                                        ^
1 error generated.
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'prank.o'
******** Compiling tf2gen ********
MEAD Installation successful.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `#include <pthread.h>` to `prmain.h` on a line by itself just before the `extern pthread_mutex_t *mu;` line

Comment: does this fix it for you on OS X, @daxim?  it *ought* to have that, but it compiles fine for me without on ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I'm on Linux, too. I'm guessing at the fix.